# Deleting larges amounts of data from SQL without growing the transaction log

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

OK I know this has been asked a lot and I thought I had found the answer but it's not working.

I need to delete a large amount of data from some SQL tables.  Copying the data I want to keep and truncating or deleting the old table is not an option.

The database is set to simple logging.

I'm only deleting 3,000 rows.

I've tried indies a BEGIN/END Transaction and without that and have a CHECKPOINT command

My understanding was doing this would cause the transaction log to not grow but I'm still getting a 100+ gig transaction log.

I'm looking for a way to delete and not grow the transaction log.

I understand that it's to roll things back if needed but I don't need to I just want to delete and not have the log filled up.

Comment: Are you doing this in a transaction or outside of a transaction? You need this outside of any transaction (including client-side) and possibly also periodic checkpointing. Please show the code you have so far

Comment: @ChrisWard wrote "Copying the data I want to keep and truncating or deleting the old table is not an option".  My questions are "Why Not" and "How many rows are in the table" and "How many rows do you want to delete"?

Answer (score 0):

kindly check VLf count also check Log_reuse in database.

```sql
SELECT [name] AS 'Database Name',
COUNT(li.database_id) AS 'VLF Count',
SUM(li.vlf_size_mb) AS 'VLF Size (MB)',
SUM(CAST(li.vlf_active AS INT)) AS 'Active VLF',
SUM(li.vlf_active*li.vlf_size_mb) AS 'Active VLF Size (MB)',
COUNT(li.database_id)-SUM(CAST(li.vlf_active AS INT)) AS 'Inactive VLF',
SUM(li.vlf_size_mb)-SUM(li.vlf_active*li.vlf_size_mb) AS 'Inactive VLF Size (MB)'
FROM sys.databases s
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_db_log_info(s.database_id) li
GROUP BY [name]
ORDER BY COUNT(li.database_id) DESC;
```

check why log reused in database which give description to resolve issue.

```sql
SELECT name, log_reuse_wait_desc FROM sys.databases;
```

Comment: Is there a reason you removed the code fence and put this back into **bold**...?

Comment: Not sure how this helps.  the second select says the DB is set to NOTHING

Comment: kindly reduce row batch 3000 to 500 so transaction will minimum ,  this may help you.